# SQL Server - Find if a column has missed alias in any Stored Procedure in a Database

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server Database, I have an existing table say tblA. 
Now I have a requirement to add a new column to that table with name 'IsActive'. There are many other tables(say tblB) with the column name 'IsActive' already existing in the Database.

Now after adding the column, I came across an existing Stored Procedure which has the following code

tblA a INNER JOIN tblB b ON a.id = b.id **WHERE IsActive = 1**

Since there is NO alias specified for the column in Where condition, this SP will throw 'Ambiguous column name 'IsActive' ' error.

There are thousands of SPs in the DB where the tblA is used.

So is there any easy way/single script to check if a column named 'IsActive' exists in any SP without any alias?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not solution for you.

But try to use this query it's may help

```
SELECT r.ROUTINE_NAME 
    ,OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(r.ROUTINE_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(r.ROUTINE_NAME)) LIKE '%WHERE IsActive = 1%'
```

Comment: That's a fine solution, but I would remove the WHERE and =1 parts - just use `%IsActive%`